# DocumentDB not working with simple MongoDB commands

Tags: c#, linq, azure-cosmosdb

I am considering DocumentDB, specially for the ability to bring my MongoDB code to work with it. DocumentDB is very fast and affordable, but I am having some difficulty:

I have this code that works on MongoDB:

```
var categoriesList = await Pessoa.Distinct<string>("Enderecos.Cidade", new BsonDocument()).ToListAsync();
```

This Exception happens:

> MongoCommandException: Command distinct failed: Command is not
>   supported.

On this code:

```
var cidades = Pedido.AsQueryable().Where(d => d.DocType == new Pedido().DocType)
                 .GroupBy(p => p.Cliente.Enderecos[0].Cidade)
                 .ToList();
```

It gives this exception:

> MongoDB.Driver.MongoCommandException: 'Command aggregate failed:
>   '$group' is not supported.'

What can I do to make it work on DocumentDB? Is there any **simple** equivalent code I can do to have this feature? Distinct / Group by on DocumentDB?

DocumentDB must support this. I will probably stay on Mongo until they release these features.

Comment: I also posted this question on https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1473eca4-4990-4f5b-b7e4-30003c69c983/documentdb-not-working-with-simple-mongodb-commands?forum=AzureDocumentDB

Answer (score 2):

Tony-

Support for GroupBy is coming. In the mean time, here are a few ways you can implement the same functionality:

- By enumerating the distinct values, then aggregating them one by one
- By using a streaming pattern on top of DocumentDB’s change feed (materialize the aggregates on write)
- By using Spark + DocumentDB

Comment: Great. Thank you for fast answer. All my workload is on Azure. DocumentDB is very fast and affordable, I would like to use it, but as I said, my software uses that two commands, that did not work after I migrated from MongoDB to DocumentDB.